# My web app on Yesod, Auth-HashDB, and PostgreSQL refuses to compile -- Couldn't match type ‘AuthEntity App’ with ‘User’

Tags: postgresql, haskell, yesod

I've been trying to give myself a crash course in Yesod, but I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong here. It's likely a conceptual failing, but I've more-or-less copy-pasted the code available on various short introductions to HashDB in an attempt to make a hashed DB authentication system, but no dice.

```
Foundation.hs:136:23:
    Couldn't match type ‘AuthEntity App’ with ‘User’
    In the expression: getAuthIdHashDB AuthR (Just . UniqueUser) creds
    In an equation for ‘getAuthId’:
        getAuthId creds = getAuthIdHashDB AuthR (Just . UniqueUser) creds
    In the instance declaration for ‘YesodAuth App’
```

From each segment of code that's relevant:

config/models:

```
User
name Text
password Text Maybe
UniqueUser name
```

Model.hs:

```
import Yesod.Auth.HashDB (HashDBUser, userPasswordHash, setPasswordHash)

import Database.Persist.Quasi (lowerCaseSettings)

...

share [mkPersist sqlSettings, mkMigrate "migrateAll"]
    $(persistFileWith lowerCaseSettings "config/models")

instance HashDBUser User where
    userPasswordHash = userPassword
    setPasswordHash h u = u { userPassword = Just h }
```

Foundations.hs:

```
...

import Yesod.Auth
import Yesod.Auth.HashDB    (authHashDBWithForm, getAuthIdHashDB, authHashDB)
import Yesod.Auth.Message   (AuthMessage (InvalidLogin))

...

instance YesodAuth App where
    type AuthId App = UserId

    loginDest _ = HomeR
    logoutDest _ = HomeR
    redirectToReferer _ = True


    authPlugins _ = [ authHashDB (Just . UniqueUser) ]

    getAuthId creds = getAuthIdHashDB AuthR (Just . UniqueUser) creds

    authHttpManager = getHttpManager
```

Any help would be appreciated. I still kind of suck at Haskell, so this is also my attempt at a crash course in it as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This typically means that you don't have an [`AuthEntity` associated type](http://haddock.stackage.org/lts-3.10/yesod-auth-1.4.8/Yesod-Auth.html#t:AuthEntity) declared, which in turn means that you don't have a [`YesodAuthPersist`](http://haddock.stackage.org/lts-3.10/yesod-auth-1.4.8/Yesod-Auth.html#t:YesodAuthPersist) instance. In your case, this is probably just:

```
instance YesodAuthPersist App where
    type AuthEntity App = User
```

This is provided by the Yesod scaffolding.